# Temporarily Saving or Caching values to be used Later in the "For Loop" Using Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I am looking to find a better solution or to make sure if my approach is good enough.

I have list of objects which I have to iterate using "for" loop where for each item in the list, Dao classes will be called using value from object. There is possibility that the value from the list item I am using to call Dao can be repeated in the list and I want to temporarily save or cache it until "for" loop completed so that I can avoid duplicate database calls. I only need the cached values until "for loop" completes. Following Code snippet is what I thought that can work but I am looking for suggestions.

Thanks in Advance.

```
public Object test_2() {
    List<TestClass> list = List.of(
            TestClass.builder().lowerCase("a").upperCase("A").build(),
            TestClass.builder().lowerCase("b").upperCase("B").build(),
            TestClass.builder().lowerCase("a").upperCase("A").build(),
            TestClass.builder().lowerCase("c").upperCase("C").build(),
            TestClass.builder().lowerCase("c").upperCase("C").build());

    HashMap<String, TestClass> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (TestClass index : list) {
        TestClass object = null;
        if (hashMap.containsKey(index.getUpperCase())) {
            object = hashMap.get(index.getUpperCase());
        } else {
            object = TestClass.builder().build();//Call to Database/External Endpoint
            hashMap.put(index.getUpperCase(), object);
        }
          //Some other processing inside for loop using object
          //will return if some condition is satisfied(Ex: If satisfied in first iteration of "for" --will return

    }
}
```

Comment: How will `object` be used?  Is it okay to use a shared `object` instance for some iterations of the loop?

Comment: The Java garbage collector will tidy this up by itself if the list is not used after the loop. For most use cases and data sets this will not be a problem unless you have millions of entries and memory or time limits in your application.

Comment: @AndrewS The data from the object will be used to do some processing and if required condition met, method will return

Comment: @sorifiend After processing of data from object. If certain conditions are met, the method will return. I am not expecting of millions of this method calls. Should I expect significantly more memory usage?

Comment: I am not sure if you are planning this for production level code or just experimenting. However, non-trivial caching itself has significant overhead of its own. Maintenance of cache in terms of stale entries, cache expiration etc. has its own complexity. Caching in general is considered when the cache can provide significant performance improvement. Caching only for a loop execution is perhaps not efficient; if it is for a proof of concept or to check for performance, your solution would be sufficient. Consider if making a few more database calls would reduce the complexity of the code or not.